# Cannot properly check model type of an instance

Tags: python, django

Cannot figure out, why "if statement" returns incorrect value

```
    next_step_type = type(next_step)()  # this returns 'Quiz' which is correct

    # if statement returns step_type_letter = 't' which is not correct
    if next_step_type is "Quiz":
        step_type_letter = 'q'
    else:
        step_type_letter = 't'
```

Comment: what is the value of next_step?

Comment: Try using `==` instead of `is` if you are comparing strings.

Comment: We do not know what you want exactly. Is `Quiz` a `class` and you want to check if `next_step_type` is an `instance` of `Quiz`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should also work and might be easier to read?

```
from .models import Quiz

# next_step is a model object, e.g. next_step = Quiz.objects.create(...)
if isinstance(next_step, Quiz):
    ...
else:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try it like this:

```
next_step_type = type(next_step)
if next_step_type is Quiz:
    step_type_letter = 'q'
else:
    step_type_letter = 't'
```

EDIT:
Or if you use isinstance():

```
if isinstance(next_step_type(), Quiz):
    step_type_letter = 'q'
else:
    step_type_letter = 't'
```